# post to facebook works, but shows up with privacy settings "only me"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

I just registered a Facebook app so I could let people post articles to their newsfeed the way gizmodo does it (http://gizmodo.com/5969817/the-hobbit-an-unexpected-masterclass-in-why-48-fps-fails).

However, the post is coming up with permissions as "only me". How do I change this? I've already changed the default permissions in the app to "friends".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://www.senseculture.com/blog/posts/75_adventure-time.php
2. Click **Like**
3. Enter some text and click **Post to Facebook**
4. See it in your News Feed. It will show up as "only me"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **Remove your application from your app settings**. [Link to app settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Second, **Go to the app from your account again and select the Public/Friends of Friends/ Friends button. Then login to the app.**

Now go to http://www.senseculture.com/blog/posts/75_adventure-time.php and follow the steps as u mentioned earlier.

The post will come on your news feed and the privacy will be of Friends of Friends/Friends.

If it helped you, consider to accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. All my friends said it worked on first try, must have been my settings.

Answer (score 1):

Under the `Permissions` section of the Facebook app setting, change `Default Activity Privacy` from `Only me` to `Public`.

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions shown to the user when they authorise your app can be overridden by them; check your privacy settings for the app and see what you've chosen for maximum visibility for posts from that app - i suspect you set it to 'only me' earlier, and won't see the prompt for 'Friends' without removing the app and reinstalling